# Android, NetworkScheduler: Running in whitelist mode. Ignoring task

Tags: android, kotlin

I think my task isn't running - when checking why, I noticed the log line:

```
NetworkScheduler: Running in whitelist mode. Ignoring task...
```

I assume this means I need to whitelist something (this task? my app?) with something (in the manifest? a user permission?).

I'm trying to schedule my task with the GcmNetworkManager...

What do I need to do to get my tasks running again?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Android API docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GcmNetworkManager):

> GCMNetworkManager API calls no longer work on devices running Android
> M and later once your app targets future Android versions ( > Android
> 10).

I upgraded my app target to test Android 11, so that's why this broke.